# How do I approximate a circle with a series of line segments?

Tags: geometry, circles

I am writing a computer program that allows me to [draw line segments between arbitrary points on a grid](http://github.com/inglonias/vgraph) as a spare time project. I wish to add a tool that allows the user to approximate circles of the form $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, where $r$ is a positive integer.

Special cases for $r \leq 2$ are trivial to handle, but problems start when I begin trying to describe how to do this when $r \geq 3$. The pattern that looks the best to me seems to be when I approximate the curve using $4r$ line segments, with $r$ line segments making up each quadrant of the circle. The trouble is that I really don't know where to begin in trying to solve this problem. I don't know what to search for, or exactly what sort of math would be required to make this happen.

So, if a user wanted to draw a circle with a radius of 5, shown here:

[image: Circle with radius of 5]

Then the resulting lines drawn would be something akin to the ones shown here in blue, with black vertices (only one quadrant demonstrated because I am lazy). Each vertex shown would be at a point where $x$ and $y$ are both integers.

[image: Circle with line segments]

Comment: I have thought about using [circle lattice points](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleLatticePoints.html) for this, but don't like the way it looks because the last line segments in each quadrant are not flat.

Comment: what determines the grid size? Can't you just start with $r=10$ which should give you a good practical discretization?

Comment: You should start from defining your goal function. One of the variants of algorithm. 1. Go through all integer numbers $i$ from zero to $\lceil r\rceil$ and find $j_{i,min}=\lfloor\sqrt{r^2-i^2}\rfloor$ and $j_{i,max}=\lceil \sqrt{r^2-i^2}\rceil$. 2. Calculate distance $d=|\sqrt{i^2+j^2}-r|$ for every point in set $\\{(i,j_{i,min}), (i,j_{i,max})\\}$. 3. In turns exclude points with maximal $d$ but only if the point to be excluded is not too far (distance from nearest point is not more than half of maximum line segment length) from remaining points in the set.

Comment: Have you heard about Bresenham circle algorithm presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) with variants ?

Comment: I had not heard about that. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up piggybacking off of the concept of [lattice points](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleLatticePoints.html). This gave me the most aesthetically pleasing circles I could get with my limitations (in my case "aesthetically pleasing" meant "as few right angles as possible")

This is the code I ended up writing. I will not mark this answer as "correct", because I am not convinced this is the absolute best way to go about this, but it's how I ended up doing things.

```
public LineSegment[] DrawWithTool(SKPointI start, SKPointI end)
    {
        //SKPointI is a pair of integers used as coordinates by the SkiaSharp drawing engine.
        int radius = Math.Max(Math.Abs(start.X - end.X),Math.Abs(start.Y - end.Y));
        List<LineSegment> lines = new List<LineSegment>();
        if (radius < 1) {
            return null;
        }
        int numVertices = 64 * radius;

        List<SKPointI> vertices = new List<SKPointI>();
        double angleSpacing = (Math.PI * 2) / numVertices;
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            double angle = i * angleSpacing;
            double rawX = radius * Math.Cos(angle);
            double rawY = radius * Math.Sin(angle);
            if (Math.Max(Math.Abs(rawX - Math.Round(rawX)), Math.Abs(rawY - Math.Round(rawY))) < FuzzRating )
            {
                vertices.Add(new SKPointI(Convert.ToInt32(rawX), Convert.ToInt32(rawY)));
            }
        }
        //Add the first element to the back of the list to ensure the circle closes.
        vertices.Add(new SKPointI(vertices[0].X, vertices[0].Y));
        for (int i = 1; i < vertices.Count; i++) {
            SKPointI offsetStart = new SKPointI(vertices[i - 1].X + start.X, vertices[i - 1].Y + start.Y);
            SKPointI offsetEnd = new SKPointI(vertices[i].X + start.X, vertices[i].Y + start.Y);
            LineSegment l = new LineSegment(offsetStart, offsetEnd);
            lines.Add(l);
        }
        return lines.ToArray();
    }
```